# How can i auto configure Spring boot to create 2 different activeMQ connection factories and JMSTemplates?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In other words receiving messages from a Queue on Server 1 to Queue on Server 2?
different Url's and different servers.

Appreciate all your help on this. 
Thanks, Kalyan

Comment: Receiving messages from Active MQ and publishing it to a different queue on Websphere Server? I tried some examples but couldnt find many examples related to what i'm doing.

Comment: Appreciate your help ! Thanks, Kalyan

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Spring Boot does not support auto-configuration for several connection factories, just like it does not support auto-configuration for several data sources.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me. So, If i do manual configuration by excluding JMSConfiguration.class ,I can achive what I'm planning to do?

Comment: you don't need to exclude anything. If you create your own config, Spring Boot will back off.

Comment: spring boot supports multiple datasources: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-two-datasources

Comment: No, it does not. That section of the doc is to explain how you can configure that yourself (of course _that_ is supported). I was referring to the auto-configuration.